# why my images are not showing in image slider with recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Actually I m new to android development and i m trying to implement my product images like a carousel with a library called "why not" using glide with recyclerview. but I m not able to see the photos like this. I am not getting how to implement a carousel like this, What i m doing wrong please help me . Please guide me someone please

I am trying to make it like this
[image]

MY Design xml

```
   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <org.imaginativeworld.whynotimagecarousel.ImageCarousel
            android:id="@+id/carousel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop">

        </org.imaginativeworld.whynotimagecarousel.ImageCarousel>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roomName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Room with kitchen"
            android:textColor="#232222"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roomRent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Rent 4500/- month"
            android:textColor="#232222"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Model Class

```
public class Rooms {

public Rooms(String carousel, String title, int rent) {
    this.carousel = carousel;
    this.title = title;
    this.rent = rent;
}

private String carousel,title;
private int rent;

public String getCarousel() {
    return carousel;
}

public void setCarousel(String carousel) {
    this.carousel = carousel;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getRent() {
    return rent;
}

public void setRent(int rent) {
    this.rent = rent;
}
```

}

My Adapter class

```
public class RoomsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomsAdapter.RoomsViewHolder>{

Context context;
ArrayList<Rooms> rooms;

public RoomsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Rooms> rooms) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rooms = rooms;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RoomsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    return new RoomsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.room_design_layout, parent, false));

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RoomsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Rooms room =  rooms.get(position);
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(room.getCarousel())
            .into(holder.carousel);
    holder.roomtitle.setText(room.getTitle());
    holder.roomrent.setText(String.valueOf(room.getRent()));


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return rooms.size();
}

public class RoomsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    ImageView carousel;
    TextView roomtitle, roomrent;

    public RoomsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        carousel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.carousel);
        roomtitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.roomName);
        roomrent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.roomRent);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you follow the instruction guide on the library website: https://github.com/ImaginativeShohag/Why-Not-Image-Carousel#usage ? Can you show the code?

Comment: brother as i am new i am not getting any idea how can i acheive carousel though i m able to do it with imageview(single image) but no idea how to get carousel images

Comment: Ok, let's start from the data. Your carousel is just a `String`. Is it the url to an image or multiple images or ...?

Comment: actually it is for single imageview brother

Comment: Then I do not understand how you want to show a carousel view if you only have one picture. First your `Rooms` model must contain multiple images to be displayed inside your `ViewHolder`

Comment: ok brother i try to make you understand 
Actually i m trying to make a carousel of images for my products with recyclerview like shown in the above photo but i m trying to make it with why not image carousel library now how can i perform it

Comment: Follow the WhyNotImageCarousel instructions? I could also just copy past them ... https://github.com/ImaginativeShohag/Why-Not-Image-Carousel#usage . They show you how to use their library and replace your recycler view.

Comment: brother sorry to say actually i m dumb literally, I just went through the instructions but I still have no idea what to do brother

Comment: actually, i m facing problem in getting them due to my naiveness

Comment: Ok, let's do it together. As I see it you first change your carousel from containing a single url as a `String` to a `List<String>` representing multiple pictures.

Comment: done brother, next what i have to do

Comment: 1) find the carousel: ImageCarousel carousel = findViewById(R.id.carousel);
2) register lifecycle: carousel.registerLifecycle(getLifecycle());
3) create the list: List<CarouselItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
4) fill the list with urls: list.add(new CarouselItem(url));
5) set list to carousel: carousel.setData(list);

Comment: brother actually i have added the  List<CarouselItem> in my Rooms Model class and i need to bind it in my recycler view how can i do it

Comment: in your `onBindViewHolder` you have your `Room`. Cannot you just get the carousel with `holder.carousel`, generate the `List<CarouselItem>` based on the urls in the `Room` object and set the list.

Comment: brother ok i got it and it is working now but there is only one problem in it

Answer (score 0):

Here is Sample Code with carousel View by using **WHY NOT IMAGE CAROUSEL** library. Check this [code](https://github.com/PM1509/Mycarousel/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/pmsa/mycarousel/MainActivity.java)

Comment: hey brother actually i want to create carousel with recycler view  and trying to implement it from last 2 days but not able if possible please guide me,
thank you brother

Comment: i found a sample code that will help you. Check this link : https://github.com/CodingWithTashi/image-slider-in-recycler-view